# How to change the hostname of Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

I'm using samba server based on Ubuntu 
I was do opening the sharing file in path `//UBUNTU` and it was working fine. until I entered this command by mistake.

```
sudo nmcli general hostname server-1
```

then I cannot open my file sharing in this path `//UBUNTU`, working fine by IP. 
 but I need to open it by old Hostname. How I can do it?

Comment: `hostnamectl set-hostname your_hostname_here`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by

```
sudo nmcli general hostname new_host_name
```

then restart network services then:

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man nmcli`:

> nmcli - command-line tool for controlling NetworkManager
>   [...]
>   nmcli general {status | hostname | permissions | logging} [ARGUMENTS...]
>   [...]
>   hostname [hostname]
>
> Get and change system hostname. With no arguments, this prints currently configured hostname. When you pass a hostname, it will be handed over to NetworkManager to be set as a new system hostname.
>
> Note that the term "system" hostname may also be referred to as "persistent" or "static" by other programs or tools. The hostname is stored in /etc/hostname file in most distributions. For example, systemd-hostnamed service uses the term "static" hostname and it only reads the /etc/hostname file when it starts.

So what you have done: With your command

> `sudo nmcli general hostname server-1`

you changed the hostname to `server-1`. So reversing what you have done by issuing the same command but instead of `server-1` typing the desired/ old hostname should solve your issue.

You could also just directly edit `/etc/hostname`, provided no other application thinks it should be different and overwrites it.